# How do I leverage react server components when I need to wrap my entire application in ThemeProvider that uses browser api to detect dark mode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I am using **NextJS** **13** with **App** router. I am fairly new to this, what I am trying to accomplish so far is have a dark / light theme mode for my application. I have the themes in my zustand store.

Here is the code for zustand theme `store.ts`:

```js
import { createJSONStorage, persist } from 'zustand/middleware'

import { createZustandChildrenStore } from './store'

export enum Theme {
  light = 'light',
  dark = 'dark',
}

type State = {
  theme: Theme
}

type Actions = {
  setCurrentTheme: (theme: Theme) => void
  theme: Theme
  isLightTheme: () => boolean
  reset: () => void
}

type ThemeStore = State & Actions

const initialState: State = {
  theme:
    window.matchMedia &&
    window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
      ? Theme.dark
      : Theme.light,
}

const useThemeStore = createZustandChildrenStore<ThemeStore>()(
  persist(
    (set, get) => ({
      ...initialState,
      setCurrentTheme: (theme: Theme) => {
        set({ theme })
      },
      isLightTheme: () => {
        return get().theme === Theme.light
      },
      reset: () => set(initialState),
    }),
    {
      name: 'themeStorage',
      storage: createJSONStorage(() => localStorage),
    }
  )
)

export { useThemeStore }
export type { ThemeStore }
```

Finally this is what I am doing in my root `layout.txs`

```js
import { inter } from '@/font';
import { Theme, useThemeStore } from '@/store/zustand/themeStore';
import { ClerkProvider } from '@clerk/nextjs';
import { dark, } from '@clerk/themes';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import '../globals.css';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Goater',
  description: "Vote for the Goat"
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  const {isLightTheme, theme, setCurrentTheme } =
    useThemeStore()

  useEffect(() => {
    window
      .matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
      .addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        event.matches
          ? setCurrentTheme(Theme.dark)
          : setCurrentTheme(Theme.light)
      })

    return () => {
      window
        .matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
        .removeEventListener('change', (event) => {
          event.matches
            ? setCurrentTheme(Theme.dark)
            : setCurrentTheme(Theme.light)
        })
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    document?.querySelector?.('html')?.setAttribute?.('data-theme', theme)
  }, [theme])

  return (
    <ClerkProvider appearance={{
      baseTheme: isLightTheme() ? undefined : dark
    }}>
        <html lang={inter.className}>
            <body>
              {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  )
}
```

as you can see, If I make this a client component, my entire application will be a client component that resides under this path.. which is going to be the case mostly except the auth routes. How can I achieve this? This seems to me a common problem but I am unable to find a solution.

To be clear: I want to leverage Next JS's SSR capabilities, all routes will be under / route mostly. example: /, /profile, /pages/ /posts/ /post/3, /page/5, /visits/4 etc. so they will all have base layout where i'll have the theme related code and that layout thus will be a client component as it needs to check browser to make decision, add event listeners etc.

Can anyone help me, or direct me to a solution with a similar problem discussed elsewhere? If I'm not clear enough, please ask me for further clarification and I'll provide.

I have tried googling ways to get around my issue, I have tried taking chatgpts help, but havent been able to find the solution so far. I am pretty sure the solution is out there and I just am not looking hard enough, I'll keep looking meanwhil.